# Is coding knowledge required to file a patent for an app?

Tags: patentability, patent-applications, patent-services, code

I have an idea in my head and I know how it will work. I can write about it in detail along with diagrams. But the problem is I don't know how to code. Can I file a patent for it with this much detail or do I need a programmer to write some sort prototype code for the app ? 
Thanks in Advance.
Pratiek.

Comment: Nothing at all stops you from filing an application. Whether or not it results in a granted patent is the question.

Answer (score 4):

"Do not know how to make it" is a fatal statement in a patent application. You need to explain how to make and use the invention. However, patents involving software or other methods generally have flowcharts. If you can explain it in words that describe the actions specified by a set of flowcharts, then you can explain it. The flowcharts need to be such that a programmer could implement it without making any other invention.